# Pulling in tweets to a tableview in Corona SDk

Tags: twitter, lua, tableview, coronasdk

I'm interested in building a tableview to pull in tweets from a twitter profile. Using, Corona SDK, the only twitter option I have found so far is a webview but we would like to display the tweets in a tableview instead. Is there any way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, most of the twitter examples for Corona SDK are sending tweets, not building a client that can read tweets.  Corona SDK works pretty well with RESTful services like Twitter and in the Sample Code there is twitter app to send a tweet that has all the necessary oAUTH code in it to allow you to connect to Twitter and do things.  It would not be hard to take that sample program and change it to fetch a list of tweets.

Once you have that data back to your Corona SDK app, then you can use the widget.newTableVew() API call to build a scrollable list of tweets.

But I'm unaware of an example that does this at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I recently found a work around for this. It may not be elegant, but it works. I first created an RSS feed with the tweets I wanted to follow. Then I fed that RSS data ( stories.description, etc.) straight into a tableview. Works pretty well. There are a bunch of examples of RSS feed readers for Corona, so you shouldn't have any trouble cobbling one together.